# Shift Column names to right and add a number to change the updated Column names

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range that needs to be shifted to the right to accommodate a new range.
I keep the column names (A, B, C, D) in a different worksheet and after I shift this range I need to update the column names in this worksheet by adding 52 so instead of (A, B, C, D) it will now be (BA, BB, BC, BD)

I keep getting an out of range error for some reason.

```
            Coln = wsSetup.Range("A1:T1")               
            ReDim ColP(UBound(Coln), UBound(Coln, 2))
            ColP(xi + 1, xj) = Split(Columns(Coln(xi, xj) + 52).Address(), "$")(2) 'get column letter
            Coln(xi + 1, xj) = Coln(xi, xj) + 52
```

Comment: What's `ColP` and `Coln`?

Comment: sorry, I updated that now

Answer (score 1):

So you need to cut and paste columns 52 columns to the right?

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wsSetup As Worksheet
    Dim Coln As Range

    Set wsSetup = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Coln = wsSetup.Range("A1:T1")

    Coln.Cut Coln.Offset(, 52)

End Sub
```

Or do you mean the column headers are literally "A", "B", "C", etc and you need to update them to "BA", "BB", "BC", etc?

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wsSetup As Worksheet
    Dim Coln As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lCellsToRight As Long

    Set wsSetup = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lCellsToRight = 52
    Coln = wsSetup.Range("A1:T1").Value

    For i = LBound(Coln, 2) To UBound(Coln, 2)
        Coln(1, i) = Replace(wsSetup.Cells(1, Coln(1, i)).Offset(, lCellsToRight).Address(0, 0), 1, vbNullString)
    Next i

    wsSetup.Range("A1:T1").Value = Coln


End Sub
```

Comment: No, I need to update the column names 52(or 26) positions to the right so Column name A becomes BA in a different worksheet, I'm basically referencing those column names in worksheet2 and I need to update them after I shift the range in worksheet1